# Disabling standard quick launch behaviour

Tags: 2010, site-definition, quick-launch

I have created a Site Definition using Visual Studio and also created a List Definition from which I use the List Instance in a web-scoped feature which activates upon creation of a subweb using the Site Definition.

Everything works perfectly and I've also managed to create my own left navigation using the XML `<NavBars>` tags in my Site Definition.

My challenge here is that when the list gets created via my feature, SharePoint tends to add `Libraries -> Listname` in the QuickLaunch. What I want to do is to disable this behaviour from happening.

Is it possible through the Site Definition or do I have to do this through code?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's a property for the list instance called something like ShowOnQuickLaunch, and you want to set that to false.

Comment: Thank you. I actually just noticed it. Have an upvote anyhow